# How to send data b/w parent and child in spfx react

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I have a parent component and i want to send data to it's child component.

I tried using the react method of passing the data but got error.

Error:

> Type '{ pdata: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.
>     Property 'pdata' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.

Below is the code

Parent file:

```js
<Modern pdata={this.state.length} />
```

Child file:

```js
import * as React from "react";
export default class Modern extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello Modern {this.props.pdata}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm you are using typescript?

Comment: yeah  i'm using typescript ver  2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is spfx uses typescript . so you need to create a interface for the props .

```
interface ModernProps {
pdata: number;
}

export default class Modern extends React.Component<ModernProps>
```

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://medium.com/innovation-and-technology/deciphering-typescripts-react-errors-8704cc9ef402) to document explaining the reason for this issue in case you are interested